# Booleans always false when Putting entities in Google App Engine datastore - Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

For some reason when I attempt to store boolean data in the Google Apps datastore, it always stores as false.

My entity definition looks like this:

```
type Link struct {
  Name          string    //Coloquial label for link. Set by original User.
  ...
  isOpen        bool      //Tells us whether anyone can rewrite the link. Set by original User.
  isPerminant   bool      //Tells us whether link should be saved forever.
  isFlagged     bool      //Tells us whether the content has ever been flagged inappropriate.
}
```

I create an object and assign values like so:

```
//Create Link from form data
l   := Link{
  Name:         r.FormValue("name"),
  ...
  isOpen:       r.FormValue("open")=="on",        
  isPerminant:  r.FormValue("perminant")=="on",
  isFlagged:    r.FormValue("flagged")=="on",
}
```

I verify the data by running the following:

```
//Put the Link in the datastore
lKey, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Link", nil), &l)
if err != nil {
  http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  return
}

var newLink Link
if err = datastore.Get(c, lKey, &newLink); err != nil {
  http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  return
}

newLink output value: {[name] ... false false false}
```

Even if I hard code in a true value for one of the is[...] properties, they all still remain false! WHHHHHHYYYY???

Comment: Does the entity appear correctly in the datastore admin [http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore](http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore)?

Comment: Mostly. I see all the other values I entered; they appear correctly. I don't see any boolean values at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try capitalizing the **`I`** in `Is`:

```
type Link struct {
    Name        string //Coloquial label for link. Set by original User.
    IsOpen      bool   //Tells us whether anyone can rewrite the link. Set by original User.
    IsPerminant bool   //Tells us whether link should be saved forever.
    IsFlagged   bool   //Tells us whether the content has ever been flagged inappropriate.
}
```

.

```
//Create Link from form data
l := Link{
    Name:        r.FormValue("name"),
    IsOpen:      r.FormValue("open") == "on",
    IsPerminant: r.FormValue("perminant") == "on",
    IsFlagged:   r.FormValue("flagged") == "on",
}
```

For a field to be saved to the datastore it must be exported. I.e. begin with an uppercase letter. For more information please read the Names section of [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names)

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton Go Uses capitalization to indicate exported (public) vs non-exported (private) methods / attributes. I couldn't find where/if this is mentioned in the AEGo docs. [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names) mentions it in the `Names` section. It can be a little confusing at first, but once you understand what's going on it really does simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the put method AFTER hardcoding the object? Make sure any changes you make are followed by put, just to be safe.

Comment: Put is the last thing I do. If I check all the form boxes and inspect the "l" object, it shows all true. Then I call put, then call get, and it shows they stored as all false.